# jQuery BlockUI Plugin - How to set a callback function when I need to unlock the BlockUI

Tags: jquery

I am working on the jQuery BlockUI Plugin and I like to adopt the style illustrated for iPhoto (ish) http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos.

I have designed the jQuery Form that will be submitted through aJax.
Here is what I would like to do:

1> After the user clicks the submit button to fire up the form to server, I pop-up such a iPhoto (ish) dialog

2> When the aJax response event returns, then I unlock this dialog.

What should I do to achieve such a feature?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unblock the UI having it triggered on the [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) event, like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $.unblockUI();
});
```

This would un-block the UI when the last AJAX request completes.  If you haven't got the first portion, there's a matching [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $.blockUI({ ...options... });
});
```

Comment: The problem of this solution is that if there is another aJax event is fired on the form, then these handlers will be incorrectly triggered.

Thank you

Comment: @q0987 - You can do the same thing in your own handler, before you call `.ajax()` and in your `success` handler for the unblock, is that what you mean?